# Using SignalR with Entity Framework to poll the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I am trying to implement SignalR in a.NET MVC5 application. I am using EF 6.0.0 and SignalR 2.2.3. I want to update the client screen whenever there's some change in the database (update,insert, delete). I've searched around and found a few articles that show how to setup SignalR to send real time messages like chat, then there are some articles that show how to do what I want to do but with ADO.NET instead of EF. [Here's](https://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency) an article I found that uses ADO.NET to achive the same thing. What can I do to implement the same thing but with EF? Here's a code snippet from the article that handles the ADO.NET part of the process:

```
public class JobInfoRepository {

public IEnumerable<JobInfo> GetData()
{

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [JobID],[Name],[LastExecutionDate],[Status]
           FROM [dbo].[JobInfo]", connection))
        {
            // Make sure the command object does not already have
            // a notification object associated with it.
            command.Notification = null;

            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                    .Select(x => new JobInfo(){ 
                        JobID = x.GetInt32(0), 
                        Name = x.GetString(1), 
                        LastExecutionDate = x.GetDateTime(2),  
                        Status  = x.GetString(3) }).ToList();                            
        }
    }        
}
```

I've also read the comments in the article and some people are saying `dependency_OnChange` method is firing continuously. Shouldn't it be fired only when we change something in a database? If it is supposed to fire continuously, we might as well use simple ajax polling and poll the db every second, right?

Is there another article explaining EF with SignalR that I can look into? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, I have found out that EF can not be used instead of ADO.NET when configuring the hub:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [JobID],[Name],[LastExecutionDate],[Status]
       FROM [dbo].[JobInfo]", connection))
```

Since it uses `SqlCommand` and not any lamba expression.

Comment: What, what are you trying to do? send updates when something in your DB Updates?  If only 1 application plugs into your data base you should just be posting a message when someone send in a request, Polling your database is very taxing

Comment: I'm not _polling_ the database, instead I've used SignalR hubs to send the updates to the client whenever there is any change in the db. Sorry for the trouble, should have not written polling in the title. I was using Ajax to poll the db previously but as you said, it's very heavy on the db so I decided to go with SignalR.

Comment: why don't you just have your webservice call the Hubs when it needs to update?

Comment: Because I don't know when the changes are going to occur. So I have to use `SqlDependency` to find out about the changes and inform the client about them.

Comment: Isn't the web service the thing that updates the DB in the first place?  If the web service is the only thing update the DB you can just have the web service call the hubs directly

Comment: Haven't thought of that. Which approach do you think is better and why? Considering that we are not actually _polling_ the db (unlike Ajax).

Comment: If you only have your web service updating then have it call signalr otherwise your duplicating the latency one to update sql and another request to communicate with sql to update the clients, your web service already has the updated data just call signalr directly